# How to rename MSI file based on build environment generated from TFS build definition?

Tags: tfs, installshield, tfsbuild

I have created 2 different build definitions pointing to the same solution file .

1. QA environment.
2. Production environment.

Output of the solution generates installer files say 'xyz.msi' for both build definitions.

**Problem** : I need to rename these msi files according to environment something like 'xyz.QA.msi' and 'xyz.Production.msi'.

What is the best way to do it? is it possible by modifying the tfs build template? or any other easy and quick solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an invoke process to call a batch file that will do rename

so the contents of the bat file is something like

```
rename xyz.msi xyz.QA.msi
```

or create a custom activity to do the same thing

you could make it generic by adding an argument value that contains your environment name and then set the value in the build definition screen, you could then pass the environment name as an argument to batch / custom activity so you would end up with

```
SET ENV=%1
rename xyz.msi xyz.%ENV%.msi
```